# How to explore Google Endpoint API hosted over HTTP without generating google chrome files in my project folder?

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

I am testing my Google Endpoint API over localhost. And to test the api locally, I am following this command suggested from google- (https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#hitting_local_api)

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\Users\Probhat\workspace\codesap" --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8888

It is working fine. I can access the API's. But the main problem here is that the command itself generating some extra files in my project folder. And the files are very irritating while developing the project.

Earlier I can easily load the api's just clicking "Load Unsafe Scripts". It did not generate the chrome files. But this is not working now.

I want to know is there any way to test the API's in Chrome without generating those files?

Comment: Do you mean the user-data-dir that you're telling it to put in your project directory?

Comment: Yes. This is my project directory-> --user-data-dir="C:\Users\Probhat\workspace\codesap"